saveAsync of express-cassandra works only when executed twice
I have the following code to save a user to a table using express-cassandra.
      await user.saveAsync((err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Error saving newRecord:", err.message);
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
      });

But this does not save the data. However, if I add a second saveAsync, it works.

You haven't provided details of how you know the user didn't get saved the first so I'm guessing that you are executing a read immediately after saveAsync().
If this is the case, there's a good chance that your app is running into a race condition where the read gets executed first before the user is saved. Since the save is asynchronous, both the read and write can be executed concurrently leading to a scenario where the user read happens before the write.
If you're absolutely convinced that the saveAsync() doesn't work the first time, you can verify it by checking the WRITETIME() of the record and compare it with when the read took place. Cheers!
